# Jinja2 renders empty HTML elements

Tags: python, html, web-applications, rendering, jinja2

I've used the following Jinja2 code to render variables into an HTML select form from a list in Python 3:

```
<select name="update_id" id="update_id">
    {% for id in ids %}
    <option value="{{ ids[id] }}">{{ ids[id] }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The resulting HTML is:

```
<select name="delete_id" id="delete_id">                
    <option value="2">2</option>  
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

I'd like the select form to include each id in the list as an option. The list I used was this:

```
ids = [1, 2, 11, 12, 13]
```

All the items in the list are integer objects. I've got Jinja2 to render the whole list into the page using an if statement, so the problem only occurs in the for loop.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HQqj.png) Here's a screenshot of the rendered list using an if statements (blue list), and the rendered items using a for loop (orange numbers). The orange numbers are exactly the same that are rendered in the select form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is 
`<option value="{{ ids[id] }}">{{ ids[id] }}</option>` , it starts taking elements from the list like `ids[1],ids[2],ids[11],ids[12],ids[13]`. You are referring the index numbers `ids[1]` means the **second element** in the ids list and here in your case that is `2`. replace this `<option value="{{ id }}">{{ id }}</option>`. Or if you want the values to be in a range then you should try using `tmplist=range(0,len(ids))` and use `{% for id in tmplist %}`

`<option value="{{ ids[id] }}">{{ ids[id] }}</option>`

Comment: Thanks so much for that, exactly what I needed.

Comment: happy i could help :)